# Condition to satisfy sequence of bounded second derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, derivatives

Suppose I have a sequence of two times continuously differentiable real functions $f_n$ which converge uniformly to a two times continuously differentiable function $f$ with rate $\rho_n$, i.e. $|f_n-f|_\infty=O(\rho_n)$. Which conditions are needed to satisfy: $$\exists\ C \in \mathbb{R};\ \forall n \in \mathbb{N},\  |f_n''|_\infty<C,$$
in english: a bounded sequence of second derivatives  of $f_n$ ?

Comment: Is your notation supposed to imply that there is a constant $K$ such that, for all $n$, $|f_n-f|_\infty\le K\rho_n$?

Comment: Is the sequence $\rho_n$ converging to $0$ somehow?

Comment: Two times yes, Andres Caicedo :)